# How to create table rows with different contents using Javascript - For Loop

Tags: javascript, css-tables

I know how to create, but what now I'm doing the longer way. I have to manually create the row and cell. Just wonder if I could use for loop to do this? I've seen some few examples, but it is totally different from my code. Can anyone help me?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table.color, th.color, td.color {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.top {
vertical-align: top;
}

.size {
font-size: 90%;
}

th.th2  {
background-color: purple;
text-align: left;
}

td.cellColor {
background-color: #FFCCFF;
text-align: left;
}

td.cellColor2 {
background-color: #CC99FF;
text-align: left;
}

td.cellC {
color: red;
}

td.cellHover:hover {
background-color: #FF33FF;
cursor: pointer;
}

td.cellHover2:hover {
background-color: #CC00FF;
cursor: pointer;
}

.size {
font-size: 90%;
}

td.colspan {
background-color: #C8C8C8;
}



</style>
</head>
<body>


<table id="myTable" width="1290px" class="color">
<tr>
<th width="60px" class="th2 color">No</th>
<th width="155px" class="th2 color">Testing</th>
<th width="100px" class="th2 color">Testing</th>
<th width="55px" class="th2 color">Testing</th>
<th width="105px" class="th2 color">Testing</th>
<th width="130px" class="th2 color">Testing</th>
<th width="50px" class="th2 color">Testing</th>
<th width="110px" class="th2 color">Testing</th>
<th width="95px" class="th2 color">Testing</th>
<th width="320px" class="th2 color">Testing</th>
<th width="30px" class="th2 color">Testing</th>
<th width="40px" class="th2 color">Testing</th>
<th width="40px" class="th2 color">Testing</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td colspan="13" class="colspan">
<p align="left" id="myBtn" onclick="myFunction()">> Click Me</p>
</td>
</tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");

    var row1 = table.insertRow(2);
    row1.setAttribute("class", "size");

    var cell1a = row1.insertCell(0);
    cell1a.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell1b = row1.insertCell(1);
    cell1b.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell1c = row1.insertCell(2);
    cell1c.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell1d = row1.insertCell(3);
    cell1d.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell1e = row1.insertCell(4);
    cell1e.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell1f = row1.insertCell(5);
    cell1f.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell1g = row1.insertCell(6);
    cell1g.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell1h = row1.insertCell(7);
    cell1h.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell1i = row1.insertCell(8);
    cell1i.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell1j = row1.insertCell(9);
    cell1j.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell1k = row1.insertCell(10);
    cell1k.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell1l = row1.insertCell(11);
    cell1l.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell1n = row1.insertCell(12);
    cell1n.setAttribute("class", "color");


    cell1a.innerHTML = "ssddsa";
    cell1b.innerHTML = "dfsafsa";
    cell1c.innerHTML = "hais";
    cell1d.innerHTML = "NA";
    cell1e.innerHTML = "NT";
    cell1f.innerHTML = "rrr";
    cell1g.innerHTML = "aa";
    cell1h.innerHTML = "czx";
    cell1i.innerHTML = "qwerty";
    cell1j.innerHTML = "ppppp";
    cell1k.innerHTML = "ds";
    cell1l.innerHTML = "year";
    cell1n.innerHTML = "kick";



    var row2 = table.insertRow(2);
    row2.setAttribute("class", "size");

    var cell2a = row2.insertCell(0);
    cell2a.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell2b = row2.insertCell(1);
    cell2b.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell2c = row2.insertCell(2);
    cell2c.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell2d = row2.insertCell(3);
    cell2d.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell2e = row2.insertCell(4);
    cell2e.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell2f = row2.insertCell(5);
    cell2f.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell2g = row2.insertCell(6);
    cell2g.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell2h = row2.insertCell(7);
    cell2h.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell2i = row2.insertCell(8);
    cell2i.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell2j = row2.insertCell(9);
    cell2j.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell2k = row2.insertCell(10);
    cell2k.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell2l = row2.insertCell(11);
    cell2l.setAttribute("class", "color");

    var cell2n = row2.insertCell(12);
    cell2n.setAttribute("class", "color");


    cell2a.innerHTML = "abc";
    cell2b.innerHTML = "def";
    cell2c.innerHTML = "ghi";
    cell2d.innerHTML = "1";
    cell2e.innerHTML = "2";
    cell2f.innerHTML = "3";
    cell2g.innerHTML = "4";
    cell2h.innerHTML = "5";
    cell2i.innerHTML = "fdsfds";
    cell2j.innerHTML = "lol";
    cell2k.innerHTML = "dsa";
    cell2l.innerHTML = "aaaa";
    cell2n.innerHTML = "b";

    document.getElementById("myBtn").setAttribute('disabled');

    }

    </script>
```

Fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/135/

Comment: If the content, attribute of those element is static or if there is any pattern than you can do this with for loop. Otherwise you have to d it manually. Like if you want to create same image element with the same image for 100 time than you can do this with for loop. If everytime the picture changes randomly you can not.

Comment: Normally you would store the data in an array, and then iterate over this array to create the row out of it, instead of mixing content data and dom creation.

Comment: Do you have data structures that contain the information to go in each row? That would be good to add in your question - with just random static text the best way is to ditch the javascript and just do the table in html.

Comment: I have solution to this but i would like to know reason of this, so i could help in such a way. And are you planning to use **JQuery**?

Comment: @Zul Hazmi, are you looking forward for the solution?